# Error when access Json Data from Php file

Tags: python, json

i have a Json Data that i can access from my own api

But the Json Data is not in a .json file its in Php file (like in the link below)

now i want to use Python to print the Data

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("https://**********.000webhostapp.com/api/value/read_all.php") as response:
    source = response.read()
data = source
for item in data['value']['temp']:
    print(item)
```

This the python Script i use

this is the main Error :

> for item in data['value']['temp']:
>   TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

The JSON looks like:

```
{"value":[{"id":"1","temp":"25.60","water":"80%","total":"5L","percent":"50%"}...
```

Comment: response.read() will return a bytes object, you need to convert it to a string and then use the json library to convert it to a dictionary.

Comment: i still new in fact can you help me with a code please

Comment: You haven't actually used the `json` library in your code

Comment: I don't get what relation to PHP is here. Can you reduce the problem? Or can you at least extend the question with a [mcve]?

Comment: @roganjosh in fact thats right 
but i use it and still get the same error 
    for item in data['value']['temp']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json.loads()` to convert a JSON string to a Python dictionary or list. Use the `decode()` method to convert the bytes to a string.

```
data = json.loads(source.decode('utf-8'))
```

You're also accessing the JSON incorrectly. `data['value']` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary by itself. The loop should be:

```
for value in data['value']:
    print(value['temp'])
```

Comment: still get the same error :
    for item in data['value']['temp']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: That's not the same error. It says "list indices", not "byte indices". That means that the JSON contains an array, not an object. You need to post a sample of the JSON so we can see how to properly access it.

Comment: In JSON, `[]` creates a list, you need to use numeric indicecs access its elements, `{}` creates a dictionary, it has string indices.

Comment: ok this is a simple :
{"value":[{"id":"1","temp":"25.60","water":"80%","total":"5L","percent":"50%"}

Comment: `for data['value'] as value: print(value['temp'])`

Comment: import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("https://**********.000webhostapp.com/api/value/read_all.php") as response:
    source = response.read()
data = json.loads(source.decode('utf-8'))

for data['value'] as value:
    print(value['temp'])

Comment: I don't see `XD` anywhere.

Comment: for data['value'] as value:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


the XD it just was foe laugh

Comment: Oops, mixed a little PHP in my Python.

Comment: oh, ok dont worry about it

Comment: Yes .. It Works 
Thanks Bro

Answer (score 0):

You are using `urlopen` to read data from a webpage which will return a `response` object. You can call `response.read()` which will return a byte-string. This is simply the sequence of bytes your website has sent.

Since you are assuming those bytes are valid JSON, you will be able to decode them to a string which you can do with the `bytes.decode` method. Assuming you're using the UTF-8 charset this would be `bytes.decode('utf-8')`

To load a JSON formatted string as a dictionary, you can use the built-in `json` module, which I see you have imported at the top of your code.

Together this will look like:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("https://**********.000webhostapp.com/api/value/read_all.php") as response:
    source = response.read()
    my_string = source.decode('utf-8')
    my_dictionary = json.loads(my_string)

for item in my_dictionary['value']['temp']:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Not working its the same error :
    for item in my_dictionary['value']['temp']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str